# Restore back all permission what if accidentally clicked delete unique permission

Tags: permissions, unique, onedrive

I accidentally clicked **delete unique permission** from one of my shared document in Onedrive. All the permissions lost, anyway for me to restore back all the permission?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestion of [@moe](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/21441/moe) putting the answer line on the top:

*I don't think that there will be any other door opened for you to restore the deleted permission except recreating it.*

When you delete the unique permission it will inherit the permission from parent site.

[image]

Just click Stop Inheriting Permission" and you will get unique permissions back, Set it again.

Comment: He is not asking how to stop inheriting permissions, he is asking how to recover the unique permissions he already had.

Comment: @Yugo, correct, and this sentence answers that: "I don't think that there will be any other door opened for you to restore the deleted permission except recreating it." If I'd rephrase the answer, I'd put the most important line at the top, and the rest of it after that.

Comment: I think that might work, but is unimportant information as it's not related with the issue per se, so it's a distracting answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Unless you had some sort of backup you can't return to the unique permissions you had.

Comment: how to set the backup?

Comment: 3rd party software for the most part, there are some powershell scripts out there that can net you some information like permissions report for sites.