# How to restore deleted unique permissions

Tags: item-level-permissions

I accidentally selected the Delete Unique Permissions (inheritance) button and now I can't seem to view certain lists.  How do I restore this back?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There is no other door opened for you to restore the deleted permission except recreating it unless you have back up.

For more information please refer to [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218834/restore-back-all-permission-what-if-accidentally-clicked-delete-unique-permissio) post.

Comment: Thank you, Aakash!  I have sent a request to our Administrator as this error is beyond my ability to fix.  Very glad to join this community as I am starting to learn SharePoint.

Answer (score 3):

You could restore permission of site, list and library by PowerShell script. The PowerShell in the article below will loop through all the web application to backup permission, you could customize the script according to your requirement.

For more detailed information, you could refer to the below articles.

SharePoint Permission Back Up and Restore in PowerShell

http://wp.ahcheng.com/2015/06/03/sharepoint-permission-back-up-and-restore-in-powershell/

Backup/restore Site, Library and document permissions

https://sppermissionbackup.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you, Joel!  I have sent a request to our Administrator as this error is beyond my ability to fix.  Very glad to join this community as I am starting to learn SharePoint.